# Getting Error while updating Account Name on contact Last Name through Trigger

Tags: trigger, after-trigger

I am using trigger to create A Contact record once Account  record is created contact will get created where Account name will be Last name of contact.

```
 trigger AcctContTrigger on Account (after insert)
{
   List<Contact> conList= new List<Contact>();
     for(Account a:Trigger.new) 
         {
           Contact c=new Contact();
           c.lastName=a.Name;
           conList.add(c);
         }
   insert conList;      
}
```

Getting Error :Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Name at line 7 column 25”
So Name is standard account field then why system doesnt recognize still

Comment: Make sure there is no existing class with the 'Account' name in your org.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to call out the specific code that is throwing the error.

Comment: the above code is working fine in my org.
@Aakriti.G please throw some light on what if you said is the main problem and why? asking because curious to know. thanks